# HTree Indexed Directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

Reading the man page of `chattr`, I came across the `I` flag for `Indexed Directory`. Upon investigation it turned out that this refers to HTree indexed directories, as described by [this paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/als01/full_papers/phillips/phillips.pdf). It says that **h**ashed **tree** provided a similar performance to BTrees, but are way simpler to implement.

After running `lsattr` in the home on my Ubuntu machine, I noticed the the Downloads directory has the Indexed Directory flag set, but nothing else has. I also noticed, that `stat --format "%s" Downloads` tells me its size was 12 KiB instead of the 4 KiB I got for all other directories in my home. I searched the Internet for further information on this topic, but only got this paper from 2001.

The system is an Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel 5.3.0-26 on an ext4 root.

My questions are:

- What's the practical difference between HTree and non-HTree directories?
- How can I create them? How was it created?
- Why isn't any directory a HTree one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any modern ext3/ext4 filesystem, all directories larger than a single filesystem block (typically 4KB) will be indexed. This happens automatically when the directory grows beyond the first block.

There isn't any particular way to "create" an htree directory, beyond adding more entries than can fit into one block (depends on filename length, maybe 60-100 files).  Once a directory grows in size, it will never be shrunk by ext4, though there are some patches floating around that may implement this one day.

Comment: So why are there both implementations of directory indexing then?

Comment: There is only one implementation of indexed directory. Non-htree directories are searched linearly. With new filesystems this should not normally happen, but older filesystems may have non-htree directories, or if there is an error detected it will clear the index flag and fall back to linear searching.

Comment: @LustreOne, would you share some source where I can find about this automatic indexing on directory growth?

Comment: Note there isn't a "index" for looking up exact filenames, per-se, since entries are inserted into the directory leaf blocks without any ordering. There is an index to find the right leaf block by the hash of the filename, and then a linear search os done within the leaf block.The split of a single directory block into an htree is done in `fs/ext4/namei.c::make_indexed_dir()`.